# How to check if MPI one-sided communication has finished?

Tags: mpi, communication, mpi-rma

I am using `MPI_Raccumulate` function which is one-sided communication from source to destination with pre-defined aggregation function.

I want to check whether all the `MPI_Raccumulate` call has finished (sender sent the data and receiver received the data successfully) at the end of the program. `MPI_Wait`, however, does not seem to be the solution to this problem; it only waits for checking whether the source buffer is updatable or not (available to user).

Is there any way (1) to check whether A specific MPI-one-sided communication call has completely finished (in sender and receiver side)? (2) to confirm that there is no send/receive MPI requests in each processor?

My application program should use one-sided communication but need to confirm that there is no more communications at the end of a specific task.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your send-Recv question. Are you using wildcards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing RMA requests only ensures local completion and thus buffer reuse. Remote completion requires one of:

- `MPI_Win_complete`, in the PSCW usage model
- `MPI_Win_fence`, in the BSP usage model
- `MPI_Win_unlock(_all)` or `MPI_Win_flush(_all)` in the passive-target usage model.

You probably don't want to use request-based RMA. The regular functions are sufficient for nearly all usage models. The only request RMA operation that is obviously useful is `MPI_Get` (Or `MPI_Get_accumulate` with `MPI_NO_OP`, which is the atomic equivalent of `MPI_Get`). And I say this as the person most responsible for these features being part of MPI-3.

Comment: thanks Jeff, BSP model is the execution model that I use. (I should have used the word, BSP :D) It seems MPI_Win_flush is the one that I want!

Comment: Most uses of `MPI_Win_fence` are better off with passive-target RMA or a non-RMA implementation, such as neighborhood collectives.  What is your communication pattern?

Comment: My application program mostly uses non-collective passive-target RMA such as MPI_Rget and MPI_Raccumulate. It brings the data, computes it and send it back asynchronously. I am using MPI_Win_lock before/after every MPI_Rget and MPI_Raccumulate calls for synchronization.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a non sequitur.  You send `flush` and I said `fence`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jeff I am having a similar question as the OP. I want to use an MPI_Win_fence to ensure that all one-sided communication has completed, but if it hasn't completed, I'd like to do some other work while it completes. Is that possible?

Comment: For example I have an stencil code that has ghost/halo layers. If the one-sided comm has completed, I can just launch my kernel in the whole memory. If it hasn't finished I can launch the kernel in smaller regions that doesn't touch ghost/halos, and when it finishes, launch it again in the region touching ghost halos. Launching one kernel is preferable if the communication has finished, because launching the two kernels does more work (some memory is accessed twice). If this extra work is overlapped with communication, it can be faster since less work has to be done after comm finishes.

Comment: @gnzlbg There are no nonblocking RMA sync functions but you can test the requests from Rget to determine if the data has arrived.